# Getting an ERROR: invalid input syntax for type date

Tags: postgresql, import, postgis

I have a postgressql database that im working on when use the plugin for the PostGIS shapefile and DBF loader to bring in the shape files directley in postgres.

I have a specific file that does not seem to want be brought in to the database. This is what ig gives me:

```
Importing with configuration: ecallotment areas, osmdata, geom, D:\Users\test\work\cadastral shp files\ECAllotment areas.shp, mode=c, dump=1, simple=0, geography=0, index=1, shape=1, srid=0
Shapefile type: Polygon
PostGIS type: MULTIPOLYGON[2]
COPY failed with the following error: ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type date: "000-8870"
CONTEXT:  COPY ecallotment areas, line 30, column date_stamp: "000-8870"

Shapefile import failed.
```

Im not 100% sure why it is giving me this error as the other tables that has been imported the same way go in to the database with no problems.

the details is pretty much the same as the rest of the data in the database.

Am i missing something or should I change something?

Comment: It's telling you the exact line, value and what the problem is. Have you tried looking at the data and seeing what is there?

Comment: What program are you using to import the data. Does it detect data types, or do you set them, because "000-8870" is manifestly not a date datatype.

Comment: This is possibly a bug between either Shapelib and/or shp2pgsql (PostGIS). Consider [filing a bug report](http://trac.osgeo.org/postgis/) with an attachment of the shapefile that doesn't work (the .dbf file, in particular).

Comment: I seem to have worked it out. When I tried to look at the data with notepad++ it gave me not much information of which i could not work with. So I used a programme called 010 Editor and that gave me the data I was looking for so I could then change the date accordingly as it was a date tht it was giving me that error. I think it might of been the way I exported the data from planet GIS programme. So im not 100% if it is a bug persay. but thanks.